# Clarification of this solution: Nash equilbirum of splitting 10 dollars between 2 people

Tags: game-theory, nash-equilibrium

So the game is each player chooses an amount between 0 and 10, if the sum is greater than 10 they win nothing. If the sum is less than or equal to 10 each player gets what they selected.

The solution states that "the Nash equilibrium of the game is any two numbers that add to 10. This is obvious because any amount greater than 10 destroys the value of the game and any amount less than 10 induces regret".

However the solution goes on to further state that "the unique Nash equilibrium is for each player to choose $5".

Where I am getting confused is that the two statements contradict each other. The first states any pair that adds to 10 is a Nash equilibrium, but then the second statement seems to suggest only 5,5 is a Nash equilibrium.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an explanation of why $(5,5)$ is not the only nash equilibria in this problem. The important thing to remember about game theory is that the two players have no idea of what the other shall choose.

Let us consider from each player's perspective.

## Player 1's perspective

From player 1's perspective player 2 has picked some choice $c_2$ such that $ 0 \leq c_2 \leq 10$. So what is player 1's most profitable decision? He/she should pick $10-c_2$. Any higher and he gets 0, any lower and he isn't maximizing profit.

## Player 2's perspective

This game is symmetric so the same hold from player 2's perspective. Player 1 has picked some choice $c_1$ such that $ 0 \leq c_1 \leq 10$ and so player 2's most profitable decision is to pick $10-c_1$. Any higher and he gets 0, any lower and he isn't maximizing profit.

So what is the optimal strategy? Well if we define the optimal strategy for player 1 as a best response function of player 2's choice ($c_2$), then $f_1(c_2) = 10-c_2$ and similarly for player 2: $f_2(c_1) = 10-c_1$, then the optimal strategy is the intersection of these two functions. These are the pure strategy nash equilibria.

This is demonstrated graphically below, where the filled circles are player 1's optimal decisions at each choice x of player 2 and the gray empty circles are player 2's optimal decisions for each choice y of player 1. Clearly the best response functions intersect at every point.

Edit: I managed to find an analogous problem to this one online. You should check it out too. It's called [splitting a dollar](http://www.math.nus.edu.sg/~matzgy/MA4264/Lnotes) (p.23).

[image: Nash equilibria]

Answer (score 3):

I am Economist and do Game Theory. So I can assure you that while {5,5} is an equilibrium of the game, it is not unique.

Any pair {x,y}, such that $x\geq0$, $y\geq0$ and $x+y=10$ is an equilibrium.

To verify that {x,y} is an equilibrium we have to verify that no player has incentives to deviate given the actions of the other (in other words, he cannot do better by choosing different action then prescribed in equilibrium given the actions prescribed for the other player by our candidate equilibrium).

Here, if player 1 chooses $x \geq 0$, player 2 chooses $y\geq 0$ and $x+y=10$ then no player has incentives to deviate. To see this consider Player 1 (the case for player 2 is analogous). Player 1 can deviate by choosing z>x or zx then, given that the other player plays $y$, the sum will be z+y>10 and hence he will get nothing. This is worse then choosing $x$ since in that case he gets $x$. Clearly, choosing $z<x$ is also not an equilibrium. In this case $z+y<10$, and Player 1 will get $z$ which is less than $x$. So again, he has no incentives to deviate. Thus, we conclude that Player 1 has no incentives to deviate. Since the case of Player 2 is analogous, we conclude that {x,y}, such that x+y=10 is an equilibrium.

A little bit more counter-intuitive might be the case $x=0$ and $y=10$. But in this case Player that chooses $x$ is indifferent to playing the proposed strategy and deviating. In the Nash Equilibrium definition we require that player has no STRICT incentives to deviate. Hence this is still equilibrium.

Answer (score 2):

I would interpret the first sentence as:

> The Nash equilibrium **must be** given by a couple of numbers that sum to $10$.

Then the second sentence doesn't contradict the first one.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't make much sense. The $(5,5)$ Nash equilibrium might seem like the most "fair" equilibrium of all the possible Nash equilibria (and this can be formalized using notions that compare different Nash equilibria) but it is definitely not the unique Nash equilibrium.

Comment: In the case where we have 3,7, this is not an equilibrium because the person who chose 3 has incentive to choose 5. Of course knowing that the other player chose 7, then 3 is the best response, but the offers are made simultaneously so they do not know what the other person has picked.

Comment: But the definition of Nash equilibrium is a strategy profile in which any player doesn't have an incentive to play differently **assuming** the other players play their strategies in the strategy profile...

Comment: That's right and isn't 5,5 the only place where the best response functions intersect?

Comment: No. At $(3,7)$, assuming the second player plays $7$, the first player doesn't want to choose $k < 3$ since he will then get $k$ instead of $3$ and doesn't want to choose $k > 3$ since he will then get $0$ instead of $3$. The same goes for the second player.

Comment: @anna_xox If you pick 9 and I pick 1, what is my incentive for picking higher. In my head you have picked your most profitable choice: 9. If I pick higher, I will get 0, if I pick lower, I will get 0, this way I get 1.

Comment: See I understand that, so then what does it mean to say 5,5 is a unique Nash equilibrium if it isn't?

Comment: @anna_xox That's why it's nonsense...

Comment: @levap Actually, I think you could reason that 5,5 is the only symmetric nash equilibrium. That is, it is the only situation where both players will have the exact same decisions to make. That's a long shot though. I think by general definitions, any of choices $x_1 + x_2 = 10$ is a nash equilibrium for this game.

Comment: @gowarth: Yes, one can argue that of all the possible Nash equilibria, the $(5,5)$ is the "fairest" but then something is missing in the quotation...

Comment: I thought in game theory the concept of 'fair' doesn't come into play. Each player only wants to maximize their own utility.

Comment: @anna_xox Exactly. That is why 5,5 is not the only nash equilibrium in this game. Ill add an answer.

Comment: There is an important difference between zero sum games and non-zero sum games. In zero sum games, one can attach a satisfactory "value" to the game and each player, by maximizing his possible profit (max min) or minimizing his possible loss (min max) reaches independently the conclusion that he wants to play a strategy guaranteeing the value. However, in a non-zero sum game, there isn't a notion of a "solution" or a value. You can talk about equilibria but usually there isn't a unique one and there is no natural procedure upon which you can justify that the players will play a specific

Comment: equilibrium or a natural way of choosing between different possible equilibria.

Comment: Sorry to beat a dead horse, but isn't a Nash equilibrium defined as the place where best response functions intersect ie 5,5.

Comment: If $b_1(s)$ is the best response of player $1$ to the strategy $s$ of player $2$ and $b_2(s)$ is the best response of player $2$ to the strategy $s$ of player $1$ then $(s,t)$ is a Nash equilibrium if and only if $b_1(t) = s$ and $b_2(s) = t$. But this happens also at $(3,7)$.

Comment: @anna_xox You are right about the intersection of the best response functions being the n.e. I've drawn the best response functions for both in my answer; they intersect at every point.